# Does UUID primary key worsen read queries if table contains 'hot' and 'cold' data in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm architecting a table which will store events. Each event will be about 100-500 bytes and it's planned to be about 500 millions of events each year. The app lifetime should be 3+ years. Newest events are "hot", because during a month after event occurred it could be extensively fetched by different queries for processing, other events could be fetched as well, but very rarely, so they are "cold". First I decided to use UUID primary key for such table, but now I'm afraid that using UUID could ruin read performance for "hot" data because of how postgres stores pages on disk. Are my fears justified or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter what data type you choose for your primary key – it will just be a couple of bytes on disk.

What I'd look into is partitioning. If you normally access new entries, you could partition by date. But this will only help if you can add a clause like `WHERE creationdate > '....'` to the queries that access the entries, because then the search will be limited to those partitions that match the condition. Partitioning would also make it easy to remove old data.

Unfortunately partitioning is not built into PostgreSQL (yet) and still takes a lot of hand-rolling. Moreover there are certain things lacking, like global indexes. But if you use UUIDs as primary key (to complete the circle and come back to your question), you wouldn't have duplicate entries anyway.

Comment: But what about data pages, stored on disk? Does postgresql sequentially fill them, so that new pages are filled only with new data? Or does postgres fill pages based on some hash transmutation of primary key? Or it doesn't matter at all?

Comment: It doesn't matter at all. Table data are store in what is aptly called a *heap*, that is, there is no order. They are stored in a table block that has enough free space. If there is no such block, the table is extended. The primary key order is kept in the primary key index, and an index doesn't mind much in which order you insert entries.

Comment: Thx Albe for your reply!